# Get all Elements in a Form

Tags: html, forms, selenium-webdriver, nested, element

I would like to use Selenium to submit a form which contains several elements. For example:

```
<form name="something">
    <input type="text" name="a">Username</input>
    <input type="password" name="b">password</input>
    <select name="c" id="c">
       <option value="1">1</option>
       <option value="2">2</option>
    </select>
    <input type="submit" name="submit">submit</input>
</form>
```

If I use find.Element(By.name) to find out the form element, how can I get its children elements a, b, and c? And input the values into these three elements then submit the form?

Another similar question is: if I get the element `a`, how to get elements `b` and `c` are in the same form and  to fill (or select) values first, then submit the form?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can use xpath to get all direct child elements of a specific element using `parent/*`.

If you already have your `form` element using `findElement()`, as below:

```
WebElement formElement = driver.findElement(By.name("something"));
List<WebElement> allFormChildElements = formElement.findElements(By.xpath("*"));
```

or directly using:

```
List<WebElement> allFormChildElements = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//form[@name='something']/*"));
```

Then look at the tag and type of each element to specify its value:

```
for (WebElement item : allFormChildElements)
{
    if (item.getTagName().equals("input"))
    {
        switch (item.getAttribute("type"))
        {
            case "text": 
                //specify text value
                break;
            case "checkbox":
                //check or uncheck
                break;
            //and so on
        }
    }
    else if (item.getTagName().equals("select"))
    {
        //select an item from the select list 
    }  
}
```

Comment: change line: if(item.getTagName() =="input") to if(item.getTagName().equals("input"))

Comment: Any idea how to get custom elements with webdriver? (http://www.html5rocks.com/en/tutorials/webcomponents/customelements/) I've tried using execute-script with `return document.body.getElementsByTagName(\"*\")` but that just returns standard html elements

Answer (score 2):

```
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get("https://www.hackerearth.com/problems/")

#find all form input fields via form name
_inputs = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//form[@name="signup-form"]//input')

for input in _inputs:                                                             
    #print attribute name of each input element 
    print input.get_attribute('name')
```

> **o/p**
>   
> first_name
>   last_name
>   email
>   password
>   submit

Comment: last line should be print input.get_attribute('name')

Answer (score 1):

Sorry, missed the point of your question first.
You can locate any element witihin the form with xpath locators, for example.
In your case

```
find.Element(By.xpath("//form/*[@name='a']"))
find.Element(By.xpath("//form/*[@name='b']"))
find.Element(By.xpath("//form/*[@name='c']"))
```

If you have multiple form tags on your page, you can specify it with any attribute as well.

```
find.Element(By.xpath("//form[@name='something']/*[@name='c']")) //as it is in your sample
```

Also you can specify form first, and work with elements within it. I'm not sure abut your syntax, but first, you need to return the form webelement into some var (let it be `form`) in any way. After that you may pass this var instead of webdriver instance.

```
form.find.Element(By.xpath('./some/child/locator'))
```

Comment: But if there are more than one form in a page, it will get all elements. But I just want to get elements in a specific form.

Comment: Thanks! But how about   if I don't know any attribute of elements. Is there a way still to find out these elements?

Comment: Kinda strange request. You _should_ know the elements attributes or at least their constant parts, if they're dynamic

Answer (score 0):

Store the form element in a variable, then use it as the search context to find the child elements:

```
WebElement formElement = driver.findElement(By.name("something"));
WebElement a = formElement.findElement(By.name("a"));
WebElement b = formElement.findElement(By.name("b"));
WebElement c = formElement.findElement(By.name("c"));

a.sendKeys("first child element [a]");
b.sendKeys("password");
c.submit();
```